# How to replace values in one dictionary that are the keys of another?

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax, idioms, set-operations

I have two dictionaries, one that stores country names and another that holds the respective country lat,long coordinates. I'd like to replace the values of `path_dict` with the values of the matching key in another dictionary.

```
pathcoord_dict = {"AED": [25.30000,55.43330], "EUR": [50.85000,4.35000],
                  "JPY": [35.68330,139.73330], "CNY": [39.91660,116.38330],
                  "GBP": [51.50000,-0.11670], "CAD": [45.42000, -75.67000],
                  "BRL": [-23.56660,-46.6332], "AUD": [ -33.91660,151.28330],
                  "NZD": [-36.88320,174.75000], "CHF": [46.23330,6.0667],
                  "NOK": [59.93330, 10.68330], "SEK": [59.38330 ,18.00000],
                  "SGD": [1.36670,103.75000], "HKD": [21.75000,115.00000],
                  "CNY": [39.91660,116.38330], "INR": [18.96670,72.83330],
                  "RUB": [55.75000, 37.61670], "MXN": [ 19.46670,-99.14990],
                  "TRY": [41.03330,29.00000], "AED": [25.30000,55.43330],
                  "BRL": [-23.56660,-46.6332]}

path_dict = {'AUD': [['USD'], ['JPY'], ['JPY'], ['EUR'], ['EUR'], ['INR'],
                     ['INR'], ['USD']], 'CHF': [['USD'], ['JPY'], ['JPY'],
                     ['EUR'], ['EUR'], ['INR'], ['INR'], ['USD']],
             'CNY': [['USD'], ['JPY'], ['JPY'], ['EUR'], ['EUR'], ['INR'],
                     ['INR'], ['USD']], 'TRY': [['USD'], ['JPY'], ['JPY'],
                     ['EUR'], ['EUR'], ['INR'], ['INR'], ['USD']],
             'AED': [['USD'], ['JPY'], ['JPY'], ['EUR'], ['EUR'], ['INR'],
                     ['INR'], ['USD']], 'GBP': [['USD'], ['JPY'], ['JPY'],
                     ['EUR'], ['EUR'], ['INR'], ['INR'], ['USD']],
             'NZD': [['USD'], ['JPY'], ['JPY'], ['EUR'], ['EUR'], ['INR'],
                     ['INR'], ['USD']], 'CAD': [['USD'], ['JPY'], ['JPY'],
                     ['EUR'], ['EUR'], ['INR'], ['INR'], ['USD']],
             'MXN': [['USD'], ['JPY'], ['JPY'], ['EUR'], ['EUR'], ['INR'],
                     ['INR'], ['USD']], 'NOK': [['USD'], ['JPY'], ['JPY'],
                     ['EUR'], ['EUR'], ['INR'], ['INR'], ['USD']],
             'RUB': [['USD'], ['JPY'], ['JPY'], ['EUR'], ['EUR'], ['INR'],
                     ['INR'], ['USD']], 'INR': [['USD'], ['JPY'], ['JPY'],
                     ['EUR'], ['EUR'], ['INR'], ['INR'], ['USD']],
             'JPY': [['USD'], ['JPY'], ['JPY'], ['EUR'], ['EUR'], ['INR'],
                     ['INR'], ['USD']],
             'BRL': [['USD'], ['JPY'], ['JPY'], ['EUR'], ['EUR'], ['INR'],
                     ['INR'], ['USD']],
             'EUR': [['USD'], ['JPY'], ['JPY'], ['EUR'], ['EUR'], ['INR'],
                     ['INR'], ['USD']], 'SEK': [['USD'], ['JPY'], ['JPY'],
                     ['EUR'], ['EUR'], ['INR'], ['INR'], ['USD']],
             'SGD': [['USD'], ['JPY'], ['JPY'], ['EUR'], ['EUR'], ['INR'],
                     ['INR'], ['USD']],
             'HKD': [['USD'], ['JPY'], ['JPY'], ['EUR'], ['EUR'], ['INR'],
                     ['INR'], ['USD']]}
```

I'm trying to get the end result to look like this

```
{'CHF': [[35.68330,139.73330], [50.85000,4.35000], [18.96670,72.83330], etc], ...}
```

Comment: Anything you tried yourself that you want to share with us?

Comment: `pathcoord_dict` is incorrect - list `['EUR']` can't be a key in dict.

Comment: If you dont try to do something yourself, why should we?

Comment: @RiggsFolly: For points, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Loop over path_dict and grab the coordinates for each element in the values list. Something like the following:

```
for k, v in path_dict.items():
  coords = [pathcoord_dict[x[0]] for x in v]
  path_dict[k] = coords
```

Answer (score 1):

If the missing entry for `"USD"` in the `pathcoord_dict` dictionary is added, you could do something like this using what is called a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-sets-and-dictionaries) expression (or display):

```
result = {country: [pathcoord_dict[i[0]] for i in path_dict[country]]
            for country in path_dict}

for country in result:
    print '{!r}: {}'.format(country, result[country])
```

Output:

```
'TRY': [[0.0, 0.0], [35.6833, 139.7333], [35.6833, 139.7333], [50.85, 4.35],
        [50.85, 4.35], [18.9667, 72.8333], [18.9667, 72.8333], [0.0, 0.0]]
'AUD': [[0.0, 0.0], [35.6833, 139.7333], [35.6833, 139.7333], [50.85, 4.35],
        [50.85, 4.35], [18.9667, 72.8333], [18.9667, 72.8333], [0.0, 0.0]], 
       ...
```